# how to pass variable in ajax using php

Tags: php, ajax

i want to pass variable following

```
$cat_d= $_POST["category_id"]; 

$results = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT   all_post.post_name,all_post.description_,all_post.Id,category.cat_name FROM  all_post  INNER JOIN category            
ON category.Id=all_post.cat_Id  where status_='VIEW' and cat_Id='$cat_d' ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT $position, $item_per_page");
$results->execute();
```

i want to pass variable from category page code given following

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#category_id').on('hidden',function(){
        var countryID = $(this).val();
        if(countryID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'../get_records.php',
                data:'category_id='+countryID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#Sucategory').html(html);

                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#Sucategory').html('<option value="">Select category first</option>');

        }
    });


});
</script>
```

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: yes sir i give details

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Do you mean you want to organize the echo data and handle it on the ajax side? For me, if I have more than one type of data of category, I would prefer use json_encode() in PHP, then praise it on Ajax.

Comment: i am using ajax to show pagination but i want to get id from category page

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#results").load("../get_records.php");  //initial page number to load
 $(".paging_link").bootpag({
    total: <?php echo $pages; ?>
 }).on("page", function(e, num){
  e.preventDefault();
  //$("#results").prepend('<div class="loading"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> Loading...</div>');
  $("#results").load("../get_records.php", {'page':num});
  
  

 });
 
 

});
</script>

Comment: i want to pass variable on get_records.php & have a hidden field which contain category id

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="category_id" id="category_id" value="<?php echo $_GET["Id"]; ?>">

Comment: please help anyone

Comment: http://www.anjschool.com/